# Prove that $J=JH=HJ$

Tags: matrices, statistics, linear-regression

The question asks for the idempotency of
\begin{align*}
H-\frac{1}{n}J
\end{align*}
where $H$ is the hat matrix for multilinear regression, $H = X(X'X)^{-1}X'$, and $J$ is the matrix of all 1's.

I proceeded by definition, i.e., wanting to show that $(H-\frac{1}{n}J)(H-\frac{1}{n}J)= H-\frac{1}{n}J$, expanding it I got:
\begin{align*}
H-\frac{1}{n}(HJ+JH)+\frac{1}{n}J
\end{align*}
where we can find that $HJ=JH$, knowing that any element of the i-th row of $HJ$ is the sum of i-th row of $H$; any element of j-th column of $JH$ is the sum of j-th column of $H$, combining with the fact that $H$ is symmetric.

How can I proceed from up here? It seems necessary that $HJ=J$, but how do we prove it?

Comment: Did you mean $H = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$? I think your question is missing additional conditions, otherwise there are plenty of examples where the conjecture is not true.

Comment: V.S.e.H. Yes, you are right on the definition of $H$.

Comment: $H$ is the projection matrix onto $\langle X \rangle$ and therefore $HJ = J$ if and only if all columns of $J$ belong to $\langle X \rangle,$ this means that $1$ is a linear combination of the columns of $X.$ This is more general than "stochasticity" of $H.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have $JH = HJ = J$ we need to have that $\mathbf{1}$ be an eigenvector of $H$ since $R(J) = \operatorname{span}(\mathbf{1})$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is a vector of all ones and $H$ is a projector (has eigenvalues $1$ or $0$). Since $H$ is an orthogonal projector onto $R(X)$, i.e. $R(X) = R(H)$, it follows that your data must contain a column of ones. In that case, since $H$ is a projector, it follows that $HX = X \implies H\mathbf{1}=\mathbf{1}$, thus $HJ = JH = J$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was too blind to see that $HX=X$, this is the key to this question!

Comment: @youngeAn You're welcome :)

Comment: "*In order to have $JH =HJ =J$ we need to have that  be stochastic*" ... why do you think $H$ is real non-negative?

Comment: @user8675309 Good point, we can't assume that. I'll rephrase to $\mathbf{1}$ must be an eigenvector of $H$.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that $X$ is a design matrix as in linear regression with an intercept, then $X$ has a column of ones. In particular
$$
HJ=\pmatrix{
H\mathbf{1}\mid H
\mathbf{1}\mid\dotsb\mid H  \mathbf{1}
}=J
$$
since $\mathbf{1}$ is in the column space of $X$ and $H$ is the projection matrix onto the column space of $X$, where the dividers indicate the columns of $HJ$.

Comment: Sri-Amirthan Theivendran Hi, I do not quite understand this, but it seems so right. Why is it that $H\mathbf{1} = \mathbf{1}$? Is there any source for its derivation? Or could you please elaborate?

Comment: @youngeAn See my answer.

Comment: Since you mention multi linear regression, I assume that the linear regression is done with an intercept term that is, the first column of $X$ is the one-vector. In particular, since $H$ is the orthogonal projection matrix onto the column space of $X$, it leaves the columns of $X$ fixed i.e. $Hx = x$ for $x$ in the column space of $X$. Since the one-vector is trivially in the column space of $X$ (it is an actual column vector of $X$) the claim follows.